# How does Bootstrap switch from one class to the next?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to understand `Bootstrap 3`'s responsiveness.  I understand in `css` if you have 2 classes on an element, then the 2nd class will override the first class.  But, when you create a responsive design with `Bootstrap`, your element will look something like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-1 col-md-6 col-lg-11"></div>
```

Is it the `css` that switches between these classes depending on the size of the screen?  Or does the `javascript` manage this?  From my understanding, the attributes in `col-lg-11` would always overwrite the other 2 classes, but obviously my understanding is incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's managed by CSS.

The CSS rules are written in a specific order, and it's this order which make Bootstrap "mobile first". You'll apply, in the right order :

- `col-xs-n`
- `col-sm-n`
- `col-md-n`
- `col-lg-n`

Example for `<div class="col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-md-6 col-lg-11"></div>` :

```
...
.col-xs-1 {}
...
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  ...
  .col-sm-1 {}
  ...
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  ...
  .col-md-6 {}
  ...
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  ...
  .col-lg-11 {}
  ...
}
```

1. You'll first have `col-xs-1` rules applied.
2. If your screen has a width >= 768px, then you apply `col-sm-1` rules. As the same element have both classes, `col-sm-1` will override `col-xs-1` (the last rule written always gain the upper hand).
3. If your screen has a width >= 992px, then you apply `col-md-6` rules, which will override `col-sm-1`.
4. If your screen has a width >= 1200px, then you apply `col-md-11` rules, which will override `col-md-6`.

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed the CSS that switches between these classes depending on the size of the screen using CSS @media queries (no javascript).

The `col-lg-11` does not "override" the others. The `col-md-6` is applied on medium width screens, and the `col-sm-1` is applied on small width screens, so in this way the other classes override the `col-lg-11`.